# Loop to Next worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that works fine for one sheet.  My current setup is changing though and I need to run this same code for each worksheet in the workbook.

I was able to get everything to flow through with this code, but then it doesn't change worksheets when it reverts back to Sub Test():

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lstrow As Long, sht As Worksheet


        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Call Dupe_Sub
        Next
End Sub

Sub Dupe_Sub()
'Highlight Duplicate Values
Dim sht As Worksheet, lstrow As Long, srcsht As Worksheet
Const UPCCol = "A"

Set srcsht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lstrow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With sht
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Color = -16383844
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 13551615
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    'Sort Duplicates to top
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        With sht

            .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range( _
                "A1:A" & lstrow), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color _
                = RGB(255, 199, 206)
            With .AutoFilter.Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End With
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: if you want the ranges to be tied to the `sht` put a `.` in front. `.Range("A1")` and `.Column("A:A")`

Comment: Add `sht` to the call `Sub Dupe_Sub(sht as Worksheet)`  then on the call `Dupe_Sub sht`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to pass the sheet into your subroutine as parameter. You shouldn't work with `ActiveSheet` anyhow.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lstrow As Long, sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Dupe_Sub(sht)
    Next
End Sub

Sub Dupe_Sub(sht As Worksheet)
   'Highlight Duplicate Values
    Dim lstrow As Long, srcsht As Worksheet
    Const UPCCol = "A"
    With sht 
        ....
    end with
end sub
```

Remark: Try to get rid of all the `select` and work with `range`-objects instead.
            .

Answer (score 0):

in Sub Test() I would add a line that activates each worksheet before calling Dupe_Sub...

It seems to me that your code runs once for each worksheet, but since it doesn't change the ActiveSheet it is running again and again on the same one.

Comment: Sub Test() :
    Dim lstrow As Long, sht As Worksheet :


        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets :
     sht.activate :
            Call Dupe_Sub :
        Next :
End Sub

Comment: Good point... maybe you set a public variable "sht" and without activating, refer back to that during Dupe_Sub.

Comment: I won't know the name of each sheet or even how many there are though.  How do I go about activating the next one without a name or anything?

Comment: the for each sht will make "sht" into the object representing each sheet one at a time, within the scope of "sht".  I like the other guy's suggestion to pass "sht" to Dupe_Sub as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
  Dim lstrow As Long, sht As Worksheet


    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Dupe_Sub sht
    Next
  End Sub

  Sub Dupe_Sub(sht as Worksheet)
  'Highlight Duplicate Values
  Dim sht As Worksheet, lstrow As Long, srcsht As Worksheet
  Const UPCCol = "A"

  lstrow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

  With sht.Columns("A:A")
    .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With .FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

  'Sort Duplicates to top
    Range("A1").AutoFilter

end with
    With sht

        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range( _
            "A1:A" & lstrow), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color _
            = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        With .AutoFilter.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
  Range("A1").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Here's what I would try first... I didn't test this, so use it on a copy of your data for safety, please.

Answer (score 0):

I actually achieved what I was going for with this at the very end of the Dupe_Sub

```
If ActiveSheet.Index = Worksheets.Count Then
Worksheets(1).Select
Else
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
End If
```

Thank you for the suggestions though and I will look into doing away with all the "activates."